# Driving directions via PHP

Tags: php, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geo

I am trying to get a driving distance to display next to my search results for a user database that I have collected the lat/long coordinates for.  I have found some examples that offer a ‘straight’ line approach, but not really the result I am looking for.  A little more background, I have several employees located around me, and I am trying to match their location to the customer’s location easily, so the distance results will change regularly.  I am programming in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to research reverse geocoding APIs (such as [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding)) to turn the coordinates back to an address (which most directions based routing APIs like to have) as well as routing APIs (such as [this driving directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests)).

As far as making all of the requests and utilizing these APIs - you can perform these tasks using php and [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: The Google APIs term of use require displaying a google map. This will work for him as long as there is some Google map displayed. The poster could add a link next to the driving distance to open a map.